Recommendations for Learning About Hypergraphs
I'm looking to deepen my understanding of hypergraphs and their applications, particularly in the context of neural networks. I have a background in mathematics from my university studies, although I did not pursue a PhD I did study graph theory.
Could you recommend some of the best books, research papers, or online resources to get started with hypergraphs? I am not sure of the best place to start as there are not many resources online:

Introductory and comprehensive books on hypergraph theory.

Academic papers or survey articles that provide a good overview of the current state of research in hypergraphs.

Online courses or lecture notes that cover hypergraphs and related combinatorial topics.

Resources specifically focusing on the application of hypergraphs in neural networks and other computational contexts.


Any suggestions on where to start or what to focus on would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help.
